# React Native: better user experience to save images in cloud from app

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3

My React Native 0.62.2 app needs to save user uploaded images file into cloud. Since it takes time to upload images and it likely would be horrible with user experience if the app is halted to wait for the upload and save to cloud being finished. Shall the app just send out the post request and data to the cloud and move on with the next? Here is the code in the app now:

```
const clickSave = async (art_obj) => {
        try {
            //save artwork to backend nodejs server
            let img_array=[], oneImg = {};
            imgs.forEach(ele => {  //<<==art_obj may have many images stored in imgs
                oneImg.fileName = helper.genRandomstring(8)+"_"+ele.fileName;
                oneImg.path = ele.path; //local path started with file:///....
                oneImg.width = ele.width;
                oneImg.height = ele.height;
                oneImg.size_kb = Math.ceil(ele.size/1024);
                oneImg.set("image_data", ele.image_data);
                img_array.push(oneImg);              
            });
            art_obj.img_array = [...img_array]; //<<===img_array will be sent to cloud data storage (such as aws S3) and save in cloud
            art_obj = JSON.stringify(art_obj);
            //assemble images
            
            let url = `${GLOBAL.BASE_URL}/api/artworks/new`;
            await helper.getAPI(url, _result, "POST", art_obj); //saving art object to the backend server. 

            //save image to cloud storage
            //shall the app just save without await so the app will not be halted and wait?
            //send image array to cloud storage to save


        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return false;
        };
    };
```